# I am passing a double into the following stored procedure but it stores the value as an integer - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure in SQL Server

```
create procedure [dbo].[netprice]
    @ItemCode44 int,
    @AgentID44 int
as
begin
    declare @netprice float = (select isnull((select(select sum (Price * Quantity)) -
                               (select isnull(sum(amount), 0) 
                                from Orders 
                                where ProcessID = 10 
                                  and orders.ContractID in (select ContractID from ItemsMoves where InAgentID=@AgentID44 and 
ItemCode=@ItemCode44) ))
/(select sum (Quantity) ),0) as netpric from ItemsMoves 

where InAgentID =@AgentID44 and Delivered=0 and ItemCode=@ItemCode44)
    return @netprice
end
```

and I call it from another stored procedure like this

```
 DECLARE @netprice float

 EXEC @netprice = netprice2 @ItemCode, @SuppID
```

The problem is when I save the value of `@netprice`, it is saved as integer and I need it to be float

Comment: Side note: I'd **strongly recommend** to stop using `float` and use another datatype instead, e.g. `decimal(p,s)`. `Float` is very susceptible to rounding errors and other issues, while `decimal` is not....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstand the return statement here. This is not the same as Object Oriented Programming languages where return allows you to carry a value back outside a function or method.

RETURN is the same as calling an exit code. It is either 0 or another none-zero integer as defined by Microsoft.  [Return (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql)

What you mean to do is return to the caller an OUTPUT value.

> Accept input parameters and return multiple
> values in the form of output parameters to the
> calling procedure or batch...
>
> OUT | OUTPUT
> Indicates that the parameter is an output parameter. Use OUTPUT parameters to return values to the caller of the procedure. text, ntext, and image parameters cannot be used as OUTPUT parameters, unless the procedure is a CLR procedure. An output parameter can be a cursor placeholder, unless the procedure is a CLR procedure. A table-value data type cannot be specified as an OUTPUT parameter of a procedure.
>
> [Create Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0):

If just one column is integer (maybe *Quantity*) - covert it to float:

```
sum(Price*cast(Quantity as float))
```

Comment: thank you for answer but all data type is float I am sure

Answer (score 0):

Stored Procedure always return int
[Return (Transact-SQL) Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0):

In your calculation the variable values must have a decimal. You are dividing 2 integers, but only one variable has an implicit conversion to a decimal. This results to a result without decimals.

You need to (implicit convert) add a decimal ,0 to both variables.

```
Int / int = int
Int / decimal = int
Decimal / decimal = decimal
```

Answered on mobile phone